# How to read all the sheets from excel files and get into an output file using Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Certainly! I have 2 excel files, each containing multiple sheets. In my existing code, using Data frames I've implemented logic to compare a specific sheet from both files, and I'm obtaining the desired results.
The problem I'm facing is that my code currently only retrieves that specific sheet from both files. However, I want to get all the other sheets in my output file, matching the structure of my input file, without making any changes to them. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

The code I implemented-

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side

df1= pd.read_excel(r'D:\\excel1.xlsx','Sheet1',na_values=\['NA'\]).fillna('')
df2= pd.read_excel(r'D:\\excel2.xlsx','Sheet2',na_values=\['NA'\]).fillna('')

df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')

df3 = pd.concat(\[df1,df2\], sort=True, copy=True)
df3a = df3.stack().explode().groupby(level=\[0,1\]).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x.unique()))).unstack(1).copy()

df3a\['status'\] = ""

df3a.loc\[\~df3a.index.isin(df2.index),'status'\] = 'old' # if not in df2 index
df3a.loc\[\~df3a.index.isin(df1.index),'status'\] = 'new'     # if not in df1 index

idx = df3.stack().groupby(level=\[0,1\]).nunique() # get modified cells.
df3a.loc\[idx.mask(idx \<= 1).dropna().index.get_level_values(0),'status'\] = 'modified'
df3a\['status'\] = df3a\['status'\].fillna('same') # assume that anything not fufilled by above rules is the same.

reorder_columns = df1.columns.tolist() + \['status'\]
df3a = df3a\[reorder_columns\]

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\\excel_output.xlsx') as writer:
df3a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=True)

workbook = load_workbook(r'D:\\excel_output.xlsx')

sheet1 = workbook\['Sheet1'\]

\#rest of the code I implemented logic to apply formatting (the sheets which I have implemented a code..........)

workbook.save(r'D:\\excel_output.xlsx')
```

--> What I'm expecting is I want to read remaining sheets as well to the my output file and the above code should also work for my logic which I implemented.